# What are Implications of calling an abstract class with static methods in a web app environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am coding a spring mvc project which is structured as follows(bottom up):-

1) There is a an abstract utility class with static feild/methods (say a User field that represents a particular user and holds information like credentials,the static methods are for accessing some rest service using the user's credentials)
2) On top of this utility class there are multiple handler classes that use this utility class's methods to get their job done,before using the methods,the handler methods set the static User field of the utility class to get a response for that particular user (I have scoped these beans as singleton),the handler classes themselves have a User feild which is set by the service class sitting on top of them
3)On top of the multiple handler classes sits a service class that uses multiple handler classes to retrieve composite data for the user
4)The controller for this particular section of functionality retireves the current logged in user from principal,creates an user object and calls the service method by passing the user object as argument to the methods it want's to call (i.e the service class dosen't have a User field only methods that accept a user field)
5)So, when the user logs in I would idealy want the user's credentials to be used to get some user specific data from the remote Rest Service

Here are my concerns:-
1) first of all since this is a web app,multiple reuests will run in multiple concurrent threads so has my decision of scoping the handler beans as singleton been prudent?
2)Same goes for the abstract utility class with the static methods,should I have taken a better approach?
3)Since the handler's are scoped as singletons,multiple users logging in and using them by setting their own credentials will pose a problem?
4)Even if I make the handlers prototype scoped and use a getterservice to supply new instances of the handler to the service class,the underlying usage of the abstract utility class (with static user field) cause problems?
5) In general am I thinking down the wrong track when it comes to web mvc app design?

I am new to Spring and Java in general and in way over my head.Any help would be appreciated.Need some desperately :(

```
AbstractUtilityClass

public abstract class AbstractUtility
{

    private static User user;

    public static void setStaticUser(User user)
    {
        AbstractUtility.user=user;
    }

    public static String requestStringGET(String url)
         throws Exception
    {
        HttpGet request;
        System.out.println("GET " + url);

        request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

        String credential = user.getUserID() + ":" + user.getApiKey();
        String encoding = new     String(Base64.encodeBase64(credential.getBytes()));
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

        String response = executeStringRequest(request);
        return response;
    }
    //Other methods
}

ImageHandler

import static restclient.AbstractUtility.requestJsonArrayGET;


@Service
public class ImageHandler implements ImageInterface
{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("baseURL")
    private String  baseURL;

    private User    user;

   // Getters and Setters for the feilds

    public void setBaseURL(String baseURL)
    {
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
    }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

// -------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public JSONArray getImages() throws Exception
    {
        setStaticUser(user);
        return (requestJsonArrayGET(
                baseURL
                    + "/some_Account/PrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups));
    }
}

CloudService
@Service

public class CloudService implements CloudInterface
{
     public CloudService(){}

     @Autowired
     private ImageInterface imageHandler;

     //Other handlers


     public void setImageHandler(ImageInterface imageHandler)
     {
        this.imageHandler = imageHandler;
     }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Object> getAllImages(User user)
    {
        ArrayList<Object> allImagess=new ArrayList<Object>();
        imageHandler.setUser(user);
        try
        {
             allImages=(ArrayList<Object>)imageHandler.getImages();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allImages;
    }
}

userPageController
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/userhome"})
public class UserPagesController
{
    @Autowired
    private CloudInterface cloudI;
    public void setCloudI(CloudInterface cloudI)
    {
        this.cloudI = cloudI;
    }
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userPageDisplay(Principal principal,Model model)
    { 
        User user=cuI.getNewUser();
        //fill the user object by fetching details from db using username       obtained from principal
        model.addAttribute("instances",cloudI.getImages(user));
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to understand the situation if you would provide sample code - ideally simplified to *just* what's relevant - rather than just describing it all.

Comment: @Jon Skeet added some code to hopefully make my problem clear

Comment: Why the down votes,adding code can be very problematic for some situations and refactoring to make it postable here is a lot of effort too,so please bear with me.Need som real help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Handlers, services, controlles can be signletons, but they must not contains fields where you store some request specific data, in your case it is user object (or some input data from forms)

2) Static methods are OK in web applications, but only if they don't access static fields. Only static fields that you can have are some constatns, loggers, services, etc.

3) Yes, it will be problem. User data will mess up between concurrent request and you will have information only about one request althoutg there were actually more at same time.

4) Prototype scope will solve your problem, but you cannot have `private static User user` field in `AbstratUtility` class.. You should pass user as method argument.  `public static String requestStringGET(String url, User user);`

5) I think that static fields and instance fiels in services is wrong way. I would use singleton bean and pass data only as method arguments to avoid many prototype scoped bean. Another approach is to use `ThreadLocal` variable if you want to save user information for current request. It is static variable, but its value is valid only for current thread/request. See [documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Comment: Thanks but one thing I am still unclear about is even though none of the handlers hold state,since they call the static methods of the abstract class concurrently wont that be a problem?

Comment: It will be OK unless all static methods of abstract class are stateless, (they don't useany field from that class, only method parameters)

Comment: @ Maroš thanks :) it realy helped...just finished refactoring now